# Why my internal links did not decrease in google webmaster tool?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, links, seo-audit

I removed a tier 2 menu mouseover menu in order to decrease internal link, which is currently 1700.

This is in reference to [How can I improve a megamenu, which may or is the cause of too many internal links?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81887/how-can-i-improve-a-megamenu-which-may-or-is-the-cause-of-too-many-internal-lin)

**NOTE : Please read the above link for better understanding.**

I checked in gwt, however, even after restructuring it has not decreased. Any thoughts?

Comment: Be patient. Things don't happen overnight.

Comment: In fact, it can take weeks or months. Do not worry about the notice in GWT. You will not be shot at dawn. You will not be arrested. You may be taxed though... no promises... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Google Webmaster Tools, go to your site, then select the gear icon at the top-right then change site settings. Then select the option to specify your own crawl rate then move the slider all the way to the right so that google can assess your site much faster.

Next, take the advice of the people who made comments to your question. That advice is *be very patient*.